# Designing a comment system using ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, comments

I'm coding a comment system for an ASP.NET application written in C#. Ideally, I want something similar to what we have on Stack Overflow. Is there an existing library that would allow me to parse specific part of HTML/BBCode (to support only Basic HTML)? Or is it simply better to write one from scratch, including the Javascript, etc.. ?

The Ajax Toolkit "Editor" control doesn't look all that safe and doesn't seem to exclude the HTML code that could be written but for which you didn't add any button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment system on SO consists of a hand rolled Markdown Editor (Can get one [here](http://wmd-editor.com/)), numerous JQuery extensions ([Another with JQuery](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/)) and main library and a number of AJAX/JSON calls done through JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow uses a custom implementation of the [**Markdown**](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) format. It's very lightweight, which means it uses a simple syntax but is quite powerful, whilst *not* being WYSIWIG. You would probably be best off going with something like [Markdown.NET](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/markdown_announced.aspx) or possibly just using the [WMD (Wysiwym Markdown Editor)](http://wmd-editor.com/).